# Can I retrieve the second to last value of a stream?

Tags: flutter, stream

I'm building a function that requires both the previous and the current value of a stream.

I managed to work that around, but I was wondering if that is some way to retrieve the second to last value of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rxdart`](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) [`pairwise`](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/PairwiseExtension/pairwise.html):

```dart
RangeStream(1, 4)
  .pairwise()
  .listen(print); // prints [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]
```

You will always get a `List` containing the current emitted value and the last one as well. Just be aware this will only emit after there are 2 items to be emitted, so if you need the first value ASAP, this might not be the best solution for you.

A simple way to solve this is to just save the emitted value to an external variable, this usually isn't much recommended as Streams are supposed to be encapsulated from external code, but for many cases this would be simpler.

If you really need the first value you can duplicate your stream and consume the first value only once, then let `pairwise()` do it's magic, here's one solution using the `async` and `rxdart` packages:

```dart
Stream<int> stream = Stream.fromIterable([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
List<Stream<int>> splitted = StreamSplitter.splitFrom(stream);

splitted[0].take(1).listen(print);    // prints 0 immediately 
splitted[1].pairwise().listen(print); // prints [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]
```

Of course you can also `merge` them and get all of it in one stream.